# Load additional objects from Core Data when a user scrolls an MKMapView

Tags: iphone, core-data, mapping, android-mapview, mkcoordinateregion

With MapKit in the iPhone 3.0 SDK, you create objects that conform to the MKAnnotation protocol. Loading these onto the MKMapView is very easy. However, when a user scrolls the MKMapView, it's time to load new annotations. A likely place to request the new objects would be in **mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:** which is called when the map's region is changed, and then add/replace the annotations with the new ones.

Specifically, I'd like to query Core Data to retrieve all objects that exist within the current **MKCoordinateRegion** (mapView.region) so that I'm loading only the objects that will be shown on the screen. The objects in Core Data have latitude and longitude attributes (and a CLLocation attribute is defined in the class' .m/.h which I can populate manually from that) and use this for a NSPredicate for finding nearby objects.

Due to the nature of how many objects exist in the Core Data database, we can not preload ALL objects as annotations or else we'll run out of memory (and it would be excruciatingly slow).

**How can I retrieve only the objects that have locations in the current mapview bounds?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry english is not my first language..

Once the user scrolls down or up.. the region values will change, particularly latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta from **regionDidChangeAnimated**. From there, you can get the bounds of your current mapView..(minlat, minlong, maxlat, maxlong)

```
minlat = current_coordinate_lat - latitudeDelta; //note everything is in dd (decimal degrees)

maxlat = current_coordinate_lat + latitudeDelta;

minlong = ...

maxlong = ...
```

Since you have the computed bounds already, then you can process which object needs to show, then add the annotation in the map. I have experimented with the values below..

See image here.. http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/703/picture1txe.png

From there.. i can do sqlite3 sql statement to get the points within that bounds..

`SELECT * FROM pois WHERE categ_id = %@ AND (sat_latitude > %f AND sat_latitude < %f) AND (sat_longitude > %f AND sat_longitude < %f)`

Comment: This general concept worked well for me! The only thing that is annoying is that it's loading objects that are just beyond the bounds of the rectangle, so the user doesn't get to see it dropping the pins. That's mostly cosmetic, so it's not a rush to solve it.

Any ideas why it's beyond the bounds? I can only assume the bounds are reporting larger that what is VISIBLE on the screen.

Thoughts?

Comment: Kevin, the reason you are (were) getting too many objects is because the latitude and longitude deltas need to both be cut in half first, as they represent the distance across the entire region, not just from the center.  So for example: minLat = currentCenter - (latDelta / 2), etc.